# OroCommerce How to Find Getter and Setter for the New Fields of Product Table

Tags: product, orocrm, orocommerce

I am using Orocommerce 4.0 in my Win10 system. I started creating my own custom bundle and I am using Controller, Services etc. in there. I did some adding products to oro_product table but needed one or two more attributes/fields to product table. Manually i added those attributes to product table in admin ui and i am able to create a product with new fields but the problem is that how can i find those new fields's getter and setter. Cause i want to be able to create new product with new fields programmaticaly. Is there someone tried this? Let me know please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There's two ways you could achieve this in Oro:

1. The Symfony PropertyAccess Component - https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/components/property_access.html

e.g.

```
use Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccess;
use Oro\Bundle\ProductBundle\Entity\Product;
$accessor = PropertyAccess::createPropertyAccessor();
$product = new Product();
$accessor->setValue($product, 'some_attribute', 'some_value');
```

2. Find the Getters/Setters in the cache

Oro generates proxy classes in the cache for the product entity which have the getters and setters listed on them. See: oro/var/cache/dev/oro_entities/Extend/Entity/EX_OroProductBundle_Product.php

Comment: Thank you i've found the way already. But thank you so so much.

Answer (score 0):

You should also consider using PhpStorm IDE with the [Oro plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8449-oro-phpstorm-plugin). It provides autocomplete for extended fields and attributes.